# How to make a plot that has x-axis for specified time frame in tcl/tk?

Tags: graph, plot, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm fairly new to tcl/tk and i'm trying to create a stripchart plot that allows me to set the time frame for x-axis example:
[Link to pic of a time graph](http://wiki.domo.com/confluence/download/attachments/27689741/graph_types_timeline1.png?version=1&modificationDate=1299607023000)

I'm able to do it with dates, like this:

```
set s [::Plotchart::createXYPlot .c [list [clock scan 2006-01-01] [clock scan 2007-01-01] ""] {0.0 100.0 20.0} \
      -xlabels {2006-01-01 2006-06-01 2007-01-01}]
```

but when i try to enter a time instead of two dates it's not working.
Thanks

Comment: What happens when you try to enter dates? How are you trying to enter dates? I have no experience using Poltchart, but when I try `set s [::Plotchart::createXYPlot .c [list [clock scan 09:00] [clock scan 10:00] ""] {0.0 100.0 20.0} \
      -xlabels {09:00 10:00 11:00}]` the result is very much what I expected after trying your command above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `clock scan`, you can parse dates and times quite easily (and the result has precision to the level of seconds). However, it is best to specify the format that you expect the time to be in, and to pick a fixed instant as baseline if you are just parsing times. When such things become common, it's best to write a helper procedure:

```
# This is just for parsing time-of-day, *NOT DATES*.
# Handles both HH:MM and HH:MM:SS...
proc timestamp {timeString} {
    if {[scan $timeString %d:%d:%d dummy dummy dummy] == 3} {
        clock scan $timeString -format %H:%M:%S -base 0 -gmt 1
    } else {
        clock scan $timeString -format %H:%M -base 0 -gmt 1
    }
}

# This should be recognizably similar
set s [::Plotchart::createXYPlot .c \
    [list [timestamp 2:40] [timestamp 7:20] [timestamp 12:00:19]] \
    {0.0 100.0 20.0} \
    -xlabels {2:40 7:20 12:00:19}]
```

If course, if you've got both times and dates then you can do a better job by picking different format(s).

Comment: Would this work for the stripchart too?? btw thanks for the answer

Comment: @Ubaldo This will work for a stripchart provided you don't use custom labels; there appears to be a bug in the axis extension code when you don't have a numeric tick length set.

Comment: I see no wonder hahaha, i'm a beginner when it comes to tcl so i didn't realize it was a bug, thanks

Comment: And fixed. Arjen Markus (the author of plotchart) is a good guy.